# Fourier Series and Delta Function

Tags: fourier-series, quantum-field-theory

Can you please help me understand what this equation means (and proof), and what exactly $\delta_{k,0}$ means.
$$\sum_{k} e^{ik} = N\delta_{k,0}$$ where $N$ is some constant. I found this equation when I was working on Phonons Hamiltonian to get to in form of uncoupled harmonic oscillator form.

Comment: Is there an equation missing from this question?

Comment: @jacob1729 Sorry about that, edited the question now.

Comment: What are the limits on the sum meant to be?

Comment: @jacob1729 There's no mention but as it is Fourier series basis function I strongly think it's infinity

Comment: Shouldn't the equation rather be something like
$$\sum_{k'} e^{i(k-k')} = N\delta_{k,0}$$

Comment: This seems to be a rewriting of the last identity in the "properties" section of the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)

Comment: @md2perpe No it is written as I've posted. I really don't understand what $$\delta_{k,0}$$ means.

Comment: The expression $\delta_{k,0}$ has value $1$ if $k=0,$ value $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @md2perpe is $$\delta_{k0}$$ and $$ \delta_{k,0} $$ the same ?

Comment: But the problem with the equation is that $k$ is bound on the left hand side, but unbound on the right hand side.

Comment: @SAK. Yes, they are the same. Some people use a comma, some don't.

Comment: This expression is confusing since, on the LHS, $k$ is a dummy suffix which is summed over, while on the RHS it is a free suffix. That doesn't make sense

Comment: @jacob1729 I think that's one use of this delta function representation, I wanted to know the difference between $\delta_{k,0}$ and $\delta_{k0}$.

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks, then I get it.

Comment: It could be $$\sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi ikn/N}=N\delta_{k,0}$$which is true

Comment: @JohnDoe So it has to be bounded in order to make sense, thanks! Got it!

Comment: Yes, I do think there have to be limits on the sum - if not, then when k=0, you'd just have a sum on infinitely many $1$s! I still think the main issue is with the free/dummy suffix $k$, which is what my comment was for - to suggest an alternative with correct suffices